# remove elements from array of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
first_obj = [{"%name":"sat","age":20,"%country":"India"},
             {"%name":"sat","age":20,"%country":"India"}]
```

how to remove the elements that dont start with %

```
first_obj= [{"%name":"sat","%country":"India"},
            {"%name":"sat","%country":"India"}]
```

Comment: Could you also provide the code you've tried??

Answer (score 1):

this does what you want

```
first_obj  = [{"%name":"sat","age":20,"%country":"India"},
             {"%name":"sat","age":20,"%country":"India"}]

first_obj  = [{x:d[x] for x in d.keys() if x.startswith("%")} for d in first_obj]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete key/value pairs from a dictionary by deleting the key:

```
for sub_dict in first_obj:
    for key in list(sub_dict.keys()):
        if not key.startswith('%'):
            del sub_dict[key]
```

I made a list copy of the keys because modifying a container whilst iterating over it could cause errors.

Comment: @NisanAbeywickrama That would remove all keys starting with `%`. Read the question again.